# Visual Studio scripts don't set up environment variables correctly

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, nmake, cl

I run the following command to setup my environment:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.8.5
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
```

I have a file `test.cpp` containing just one line: `#include <type_traits>` as shown here:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\env-setup> cat .\test.cpp
#include <type_traits>
```

When I run the following I get errors:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\env-setup> cl -c test.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26730 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: type_traits: no include path set
```

Can anybody give me a hint why `vcvarsall.bat` is not setting up my environment variables correctly. I also have tried `vcvars64.bat`, `vcvars32.bat` and others with no luck!

Comment: Try it in a command prompt, not PowerShell.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You're right. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RetiredNinja commented, I was running the commands on PowerShell. The problem is resolved by using a command prompt!

Comment: But anyway, how do you run it from PowerShell ?

Comment: @AlexeyKhrenov Looks like their tools are expected to be run on Command Prompt. I'm not sure. Maybe you could run them by PowerShell. But I'm not aware how.